# join plenty of files in python

Tags: python, newline

```
from itertools import chain


 infiles = [open('{}_example.txt'.format(i+1), 'r') for i in xrange(100)]
   with open('example.txt', 'w') as fout:
      for lines in chain(*infiles):
           fout.write(lines)
```

I used this but the problem is the first line of the next file joined with the last of the previous file.

Comment: is each `lines` actually a set of all lines for a file, or is it just one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a newline character

```
  for lines in chain(*infiles):
       fout.write(lines)
       if not lines.endswith('\n'):
           fout.write('\n')
```

---

As suggested by [mtth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046703/join-plenty-of-files-in-python/15046730#comment21151206_15046730), you could do it file-by-file:

```
from itertools import chain


infiles = [open('{}_example.txt'.format(i+1), 'r') for i in xrange(100)]
with open('example.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for infile in infiles:
        fout.write(infile.read())
        fout.write('\n')
```

Comment: i tried that adds a new line in the every existing line of file

Comment: Calling `endswith` at each line will significantly slow down your code. A simple for loop on the file names, adding a `\n` between each, would be much faster.

Comment: from itertools import chain

infiles = [open('{}_example.txt'.format(i+1), 'r') for i in xrange(100)]
with open('example.txt', 'w') as fout:
     for lines in chain(*infiles):
       fout.write(lines)
       if not lines.endswith('\n'):
           fout.write('\n')

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn’t open all files at once but rather open one at a time. Also you don’t really need to iterate through the lines (making Python normalize and strip newline characters); just read the files as a whole (you could even read/write them as binary to prevent Python from processing them in any way).

```
fileNames = ['{}_example.txt'.format(i+1) for i in xrange(100)]
with open('example.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for fileName in fileNames:
        with open(fileName, 'r') as fin:
            fout.write(fin.read())
            fout.write('\n') # if you want that
```

Comment: I agree that this is better code, but I don't think it will fix the problem with the conjoined lines. I suspect that is cause by some (or all) of the input files not having a newline on the last line of the file. To fix it, you can put a `fout.write('\n')` at the end of the code (though this will not work correctly if some files have newlines and others do not). You could store `fin.read()` into a variable, then inspect it's last character to see if it's `'\n'` or not. Or I suppose you could preprocess the files (or change the code that generates them) instead.